# How to make rider prompt me for arguments in Run configuration

Tags: rider

I found someone mentioned I can use $Prompt$ for Intellij. It does not seem like working in Rider. I can add an external tool of Macro using `$Prompt` in Argument. But how can I get its value and pass back to Configuration? Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out?